# As well As vs And

Tags: grammar

For the following application, should I use "**As well A**s" or  "**And**"?

Figure 1 presents the evolution process, **as well as** experimental results.

Figure 1 presents the evolution process, **and** experimental results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "as well as".

I'm not a linguist, but to me using "and" places both at the same level of importance.
You want emphasis on *evolution process*. The *experimental results* are just a bonus in this context.

"and" also sounds common.